# BOX events api stopped working as of 23rd July 2012 10:00am PST?

Tags: box-api

We have noticed that as of 23rd July 2012 10:00am PST events api stopped working.

The call used to test this is:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/events?steam_position=now -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=key&auth_token=token
```

then then output of the above is passed to the following command:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/events?steam_position=32423423 -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=key&auth_token=token
```

We are getting following errors for all our accounts:

```
{"type":"error","status":500,
 "code":"internal_server_error",
 "help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors", 
 "message": "Internal Server Error",
 "request_id":"1740663416500dc42663d5a"})
```

We tried with different accounts and api keys but seems thing do not work any more.

If there a way to check status of API?

Comment: The message indicates it's a problem with their server, maybe try contacting them?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** the issue has been resolved, and the endpoint should be working per usual. As a sidenote, https://api.box.com/2.0 is the supported endpoint for Box API v2–errors generated from https://www.box.com/api/2.0 aren't guaranteed to be formatted in JSON/XML.

This appears to be an issue on our end as indicated by the 500 error. We're investigating currently and will update when the issue is resolved.